# How do I get the ASCII value of a string that is called upon by a list in python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ascii, ord

So here is my code (mind the tiny syntax mistakes:

```
UserID = input("Please enter your UserID ")

if len(UserID) !=6:
    print("Wrong Format")

elif UserID[:1] == (UserID[:1]).lower():
    print("Wrong Format")

elif UserID[1:3] == (UserID[1:3]).upper():
    print("Wrong Format")

elif UserID[3:] > ord(UserID[3:]):
    print("Wrong Format")

else
    print("Correct Format")
```

Basically, the purpose of this program is to have a UserID of 6 characters with one upper case letter, two lower case letters and 3 digits in the format

***Abc123***

I run into an issue here

```
elif UserID[3:] > ord(UserID[3:]):
    print("Wrong Format")
```

where the ord() function cannot evaluate the ASCII equivalent of a list.
I know it is supposed to be for characters so I am stuck as to what to do.
This section of the code is to ensure that any number from the 3rd element onwards is a number so it is less than the ascii equivalent of 9.

Comment: Have you tried `elif UserID[3:].isdigit():`?

Comment: This sounds like it would (I can't believe I'm saying this) be simpler to do with a regex.

Comment: @zondo You should probably post that as an answer.

Comment: Yeah it worked I just needed to add an == false to the end but thanks. By the way what is a regex? I'm new to coding.

Comment: @AmmarKhazal Regex is how [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) are commonly named. It's used to check simple patterns in languages, for example how variables, functions and classes can be named and how not

Answer (score 1):

To see if a string is composed only of integers, you can use `str.isdigit()`:

```
elif not UserID[3:].isdigit():
    print("Wrong Format")
```

Apparently, (from the comments), there are some things for which `str.isdigit()` returns True even if it isn't an integer.  To fix that, do this:

```
elif not all(c in "0123456789" for c in UserID[3:]):
    print("Wrong Format")
```

Comment: Nice, missed that one :) Note though that this will include other unicode digits as `u'६'` that he may or may not want to include.

Comment: `str.isdigit()` returns False for that.  Do you think it shouldn't or he might not want it to?

Comment: Strange `>>> u'६'.isdigit()` on my system gives `True`

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: That is strange.  I added a second solution for cases like those.

Answer (score 1):

Just for reference, here's how you'd validate the whole username with a regex;

```
import re

if re.match('^[A-Z][a-z]{2}[0-9]{3}$', UserID):
    print("Correct Format")
else:
    print("Wrong Format")
```

In your existing code, to check they're all numeric you don't need `ord`, you can just compare all characters that they're between `0` and `9` inclusive;

```
if not all(c >= '0' and c <= '9' for c in UserID[3:]):
    print("Wrong format")
```

Comment: You should `import re` module to use regex. Also you don't need to use `^` at the begining of the regex if you want to use `re.match`

Comment: @Mr.E Yes, sorry, that wasn't really obvious. Fixed.

Comment: @Joachin Isaksson, just pointed it cause OP said he was new to programming and doesn't know what regex are

Answer (score 0):

Could just be simplified to:

```
UserID = input("Please enter your UserID ")

if ( (len(UserID) !=6) or UserID[0].islower() 
     or UserID[1:3].isupper() or not UserID[3:].isdigit() ) :
    print("Wrong Format")

else
    print("Correct Format")
```